# Is it possible to integrate Salesforce or facebook in jBPM

Tags: jboss, drools, jbpm

I am eagerly to know is there any possible way to do Facebook or Salesforce integration with jBPM. I have googled and didn't get any stuff regarding the salesforce/FB integration. If possible, please share the resource or reference document so that I can do this in my current POC application.

I am using drools engine so if its using Drools also please share.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to invoke the API's of Facebook/Salesforce then it can be possible. You can create custom service task/workitem handler and invoke the API's in create service task.

Regards
Abhijeet.